# Spring MVC: I can't modify the prodcutcode (primary key)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating a simple CRUD project and having a problem modifying the primary key with the Update method.

This is done through the Json; while for the other fields I have no problems, the only problem I am having is in changing the primary key.

Here the code:

Controller:

```js
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updpro/{productcode}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, @PathVariable("productcode") String productcode){
        product.setProductcode(productcode);
        return productDao.updateProduct(product);
    }
```

Dao:

```js
public boolean updateProduct(Product product) {
        boolean status=false;
        try {
        jdbcTemplate.update("update products set productcode=?, name=?, category=? where productcode=?", product.getProductcode(), product.getName(), product.getCategory(), product.getProductcode());
        status=true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use productCode as primary key, a primary key is not supposed to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong before setting productcode assign the old value to some variable.

```
public boolean updateProduct(@RequestBody Product product, 
@PathVariable("productcode") String productcode){
    String oldvalue  = product.getProductCode();
    product.setProductcode(productcode);
    return productDao.updateProduct(product, oldvalue);
}
```

Modify value as below.

```
jdbcTemplate.update("update products set productcode=?, 
name=?, category=? where productcode=?", 
product.getProductcode(), product.getName(), 
product.getCategory(), oldvalue);
```